# Pass object to webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have

a webservice:

```
package axis2;
public class Number {
    public numb getNumber(numb nr){
        return nr;
}
}
```

the class numb:

```
package axis2;
public class numb {
    private int val;

    public numb(int val)
    {
            this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal() {
            return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
            this.val= val;
    }
}
```

How can i pass as a parameter to the service an object and return an object?

```
package axis2;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import axis2.NumberStub.GetNumberResponse;
public class ServiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException   {
        numb nr=new numb(4);
        NumberStub stub = new NumberStub();
        GetNumberResponse res = stub.getNumber(nr);
        System.out.println(res.get_return());
        }
}
```

I get an error:

```
The method getNumber(NumberStub.GetNumber) in the type NumberStub is not applicable for the arguments (numb)
```

When i try this.

Answer (score 0):

It's far easier to just pass/return a primitive - in your case, pass/return an `int`, and just use `numb` internally. I.e.:

```
public class Number {
    public int getNumber(int nr){
        numb n = new numb(nr);
        // do your thing here...
        return n.getVal ( );
    }
}
```

That said, if you really want to pass objects, one option is to look into [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html). Basically, using JAXB you can marshall/unmarshall objects to/from XML - that is, your service will accept an XML representation of a `numb`, and return an XML representation of the result.

Mind you, the problem you've got is your call to `stub.getNumber(nr);`. I'm gathering that your `NumberStub` class doesn't have a method called `getNumber` that takes a `numb` as an argument.